# Maxima function that check if each elements satisfies a condition

Tags: maxima

I have a lot of code like this:

```
ans: [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]];
condition: length(sublist(ans, lambda([u], length(u) = 4)) # length(ans));
```

In other languages the standard library provides a function like `any` or `every` to check for conditions like this. Does maxima provide a function like this? I'm searching for a function that could express the above in the following way:

```
ans: [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]];
condition: every(ans, lambda([u], length(u) = 4));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, indeed, an `every` [in maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_35.html#SEC188):

```
every(lambda([u], length(u) = 4), [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[1,1,1,1]]);
    true
every(lambda([u], length(u) = 4), ans);
    false
```

Comment: Nice! Does there exist also something like `any`?

Comment: There is [`some`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_35.html#Item_003a-some).